# The formula field is showing a negative value calculating the two date time fields

Tags: formula, case, formula-field, datetime

We have a formula field that will calculate the number of days (excluding weekends) between two Date/Time fields.

Please find the formula below

```
ROUND(24*((5*FLOOR((DATEVALUE(First_Response__c)-DATE(1900,01,01))/7) + MIN(5,MOD(DATEVALUE(First_Response__c)-DATE(1900,01,01), 7) + MIN(1, (MOD(First_Response__c -DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-01 00:00:00'), 1))) )) - (5*FLOOR((DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)-DATE(1900,01,01))/7) + MIN(5, MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)-DATE(1900,01,01), 7) + MIN(1, (MOD(CreatedDate-DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-01 00:00:00'), 1))) )) ),2)
```

Please find the image that has the negative value

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you need the difference between two dates?

Comment: @Reshma difference between two datetime excluding the weekends

Comment: If you want to factor [`BusinessHours`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_businesshours.htm) into your calculation, `Apex` is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

If the value of your formula is consistently right, just negative, then maybe just add * -1 at the end of the formula. Or add a second field that gives the absolute value - i.e., ABS(Field__c)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to switch calculations to look `CreatedDate - First_Response__c`:

```
ROUND( 24 * 
 ((5*FLOOR((DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)-DATE(1900,01,01))/7)
   + MIN(5, MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)-DATE(1900,01,01), 7)
    + MIN(1, (MOD(CreatedDate-DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-01 00:00:00'), 1)))
    )
   )
   -
   (5*FLOOR((DATEVALUE(First_Response__c)-DATE(1900,01,01))/7)
   + MIN(5,MOD(DATEVALUE(First_Response__c)-DATE(1900,01,01), 7)
    + MIN(1, (MOD(First_Response__c -DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-01 00:00:00'), 1)))
    )
   )
 )
,2)
```